# Consulta sobre php envió de formulario

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, backend

Estoy haciendo un php para un formulario, lo quería saber si hay alguna forma de que cuando completo un formulario y lo envía no llegue a correo no deseado si desde php se puede hacer algo? o si eso directamente es algo la de configuracion del correo. Adjunto el php que estoy haciendo.

```html
<?php
$remitente = $_POST['email'];
$destinatario = 'xxxxxxxx'; //xxxxx en esta línea va el mail del destinatario, puede ser una cuenta de hotmail, yahoo, gmail, etc
$asunto = 'Consulta Bricsa'; // acá se puede modificar el asunto del mail
if (!$_POST){
?>

<?php
}else{
     
    $cuerpo = "Nombre: " . $_POST["nombre"] . "\r \n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Empresa: " . $_POST["empresa"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Telefono: " . $_POST["telefono"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Consulta: " . $_POST["consulta"] . "\r\n";
    //las líneas de arriba definen el contenido del mail. Las palabras que están dentro de $_POST[""] deben coincidir con el "name" de cada campo. 
    // Si se agrega un campo al formulario, hay que agregarlo acá.

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['empresa']."\" <".$remitente.">\n";

    mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers);
    
    include 'confirmacion.html'; //se debe crear un html que confirma el envío
}
?>
```

Comment: Te dejo un articulo para leas y entiendas un poco mas. https://cli.ginernet.com/knowledgebase/12/Mis-emails-llegan-como-SPAM-iComo-lo-soluciono.html

Comment: Gracias por la información Mauricio

Answer (score 0):

El problema como tal no es PHP, que el correo llegue a **no deseado** es algo que puede ocurrir en cualquier lenguaje de programación, el problema realmente es la cuenta que estás usando para enviar el correo, en PHP es muy común que los proveedores de hosting te permitan enviar correo desde una cuenta generica del servidor (usando como en tu caso la función **mail**), dado es una cuenta abierta a todo el mundo muchas otros aprovecharan esto para enviar SPAM y finalmente el servidor de envío es marcado como fuente SPAM causando que tu mensaje siempre llegue a **no deseado**. Para evitar esto lo que tienes que hacer es enviar tu correo desde una cuenta real de correo y no la del servidor, esto seguramente incluirá realizar el proceso de autenticación, para facilitar lo anterior te recomiendo usar por ej: **PHPMailer**, es una librería que te facilitará mucho este trabajo.

Comment: Gracias Jonnathan por la información que me has dado.